# Задать каждому imageview свою мелодию

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!
Имеется 7 imageview такого плана

```
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/litva"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
```

Создал массив MediaPlayer и иниц. его:

```
mediaPlayers[0] = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.belarus);
    mediaPlayers[1]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.russian);
    mediaPlayers[2]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.ukraina);
    mediaPlayers[3]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.litva);
    mediaPlayers[4]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.england);
   mediaPlayers[5]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.litva);
mediaPlayers[6]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.france);
```

В case:

```
case R.id.b1:
mediaPlayers[0].start();
```

Заданная мелодия воспроизводиться, однако,как мне реализовать кнопку отключения звука,и если я выбираю след. case case R.id.b2: ,то запускается новая мелодия но и предыдущая продолжает играть+когда свернул приложение мелодия так же играет. Подскажите пожалуйста,как решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 3):

Отключение звука

```
setVolume(0f, 0f);
    //где
    private void setVolume(float leftVolume, float rightVolume) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaPlayers.length; i++) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayers[i];
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(leftVolume, rightVolume);
        }
    }
```

Для остановки предыдущей мелодий при нажатии на новую можно сделать так

```
case R.id.b1:
    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
    mediaPlayers[0].start();
```

где

```
 private void stopPlayerIfNeeded() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mediaPlayers.length; i++) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayers[i];
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

для остановки проигрывания при сворачивании приложения также можно использовать stopPlayerIfNeeded() в onPause() - этот метод activity или fragment'a

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: подскажите, а метод onPause() нужно где-то вызывать ,т.е когда приложение свернули

Comment: onPause()  это метод активити или фрагмента он сам вызовется, когда приложение свернется, подробнее об этом можно посмотреть тут http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/lifecycle.php, аналогично есть жизненный цикл фрагмента, он немного отличается от жизненного цикла активити

Comment: такой вопрос:
если мне нужно откл. звук то я вызываю метод с такими параметрами:
                        setVolume(0f, 0f);
а если вкл. звук то

                        setVolume(100f, 0f);

Comment: @upward если хотите включить звук то так  setVolume(1.0f,1.0f); диапазон изменений от 0 до 1, первый аргумент метода для левого динамика, второй соответственно для правого динамика

Comment: понял,спасибо.
скажите, у меня есть такой метод:
http://pastebin.com/yxbGs3uS
что-то звук не выключается по нажатию

Comment: где вы вызываете private void fab()? где инициализируете mediaPlayers?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38467/discussion-between-upward-and-yury-pashkov).

Comment: вызываю в onCreate
говнокрод,но все же) 
[http://paste.ofcode.org/wLw7uSsn3M5uVzcUcXu2RB ]
В самом низу мои мметоды